# amCharts set maximum Y axis and X axis values are missing from bar labels charts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am using amCharts to prepare bar chart

Please check the Fiddle for my bar chart as follows:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/santhucool007/L3c3gvzg/)

- I am getting the maximum value of Y axis as 150. I need **maximum value of Y axis as 100**.
- I am getting the **X-axis values as 1,4,7,10 only. I need the values in
  all bars as 1,2,3...10.**
- I need label of Y axis as percentage and X axis as question numbers

What I tried to putting Maximum for Y axis as follows:

I have added this lines for handling Y axis as follows:

```
    valueAxis.autoGridCount = false;
    valueAxis.gridCount = 10;
    valueAxis.labelFrequency = 100;
```

But not getting. Please guide me!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Value axis scale

To set fixed scale for your value axis, use [`minimum`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#minimum) and [`maximum`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#maximum) properties:

```
valueAxis.minimum = 0;
valueAxis.maximum = 100;
```

### Category (horizontal) axis label frequency

The chart automatically tries to determine the frequency of the labels based on available space so that the axis does not seem cluttered.

To force a certain number of grid lines on a category axis, use [`autoGridCount`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#autoGridCount) and [`gridCount`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#gridCount) properties of the chart's `categoryAxis`. (note that it's `categoryAxis`, not `valueAxis` as you have in your code)

```
chart.categoryAxis.autoGridCount = false;
chart.categoryAxis.gridCount = 10;
```

### Adding percent sign to value axis labels

You can use value axis' [`unit`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#unit) and [`unitPosition`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#unitPosition) properties to add any characters next to the values.

```
valueAxis.unit = "%";
valueAxis.unitPosition = "right";
```

Here's your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L3c3gvzg/1/) updated with all of the above.

Comment: you are amazing buddy. I more thing How can put label for x axis like Question Numbers-> and Y axis Percentage - >

Comment: Got it added titles!!